# In MVC, can model make use of services to load some data into a list box of a view?

Tags: actionscript-3, model-view-controller

Is it legal In MVC, so that a "model" make use of "services" to load some data ( from web) so that the data after loading can be passed into a  list box of a "view" ?

My focus is on "Can Model make use of Services directly for such purposes?"

V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Anshu's answer but I'm personally flexible about this kind of thing on my own projects if I plan them to be very small scale, that is it doesn't seem to always be worth the time to create the clear MVC separation.  There's also MVVM based on MVC, some decent info on that on wikipedia and you can find it elsewhere http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel

There's no set in stone rules when it comes to design pattern usage, but if you set your own rules and work within them (particularly adhering to MVC in one or more layers of abstraction) can be helpful particularly on large projects or where a team is involved.

So the answer to your question about a model making use of services is yes this is possible, is it conforming to a strict MVC pattern, no.

The model should simply be the structure that holds the data in whatever way the data relates to other data, that's what the model is made up of.  The controller handles the dirty work of making the calls to the service and updating the model.  The view simply is bound to or updated when changes to the model occur and makes use of the controller (usually in as3 by using event handlers on ui components) to make the right updates to the model (or calls to then update the model).

You'll likely have extra helper classes that may sort of fit somewhere in between or outside of the parts that make up the model the view or the controller, this is okay but you should be conscious of what purpose these serve and document them well and make sure it wouldn't make sense for them to somehow be handled more elegantly within the whole setup.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, its rather the responsibility of the `Controller` to make use of `services` and populate the `model` with the data obtained from services.

[This link](http://www.swinburne.edu.au/design/tutorials/P-flash/T-The-Model-View-Controller-Design-Pattern-in-Actionscript-3/ID-144/) should provide more clarity about the responsibilities of Model, View and controller in Actionscript-3